# Looking for a way to measure trail and error query alternatives

Tags: sql-server, performance, query-performance

I would like to tune my query but i found that i can not measure the execution time correctly because SQL is using cache and some other optimizations so every time i'm executing the same query i am getting a different statistics.

I would like to find a away to get the same statistics every time i'm executing the same query.

I tried to run the following before every execution but with no success:

```
DBCC FreeSystemCache 
DBCC FreeProcCache 
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS WITH NO_INFOMSGS
```

Comment: You should not measure the **time**, it can include transition to client via network (depends on network state at a moment), your query can wait for something(depends on other activity on your server), etc. What you should measure instead is **IO statistics**

Comment: @sepupic what is the best way to get the commutative IO Statistics and which param from that is the most important?

Comment: Use **set statistics io on** to get the statistics (you can also turn it on in SSMS and get it every time you execute a query), pay attention to **logical** reads